# What is the meaning of include.lowest in reclassify raster package [r]

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

Given the definition of open internal (does not include end points) and closed interval (includes end points), it's easy to understand the `right` argument in `reclassify`. But I am confused on the `include.lowest`argument. It mentions

> indicating if a value equal to the lowest value in rcl (or highest
>   value in the second column, for right = FALSE) should be included

the lowest value in rcl would be the first value, which according to `right` is not included by default, so setting include.lowest to true will include the lowest value. But the part about the "highest value in the second column", I don't understand what it's referring to. And what does "for right = FALSE" mean? The highest value in the second column should already be included anyway.

so if I have rcl=c(0,1,5, 1,Inf,10) by default it means 0>x>=1 becomes 5, and x>1 becomes 10. What happens if include.lowest is TRUE? 0>=x>=1 and....?

I find it confusing because the example given on the reclassify help file says that

> all values >= 0 and <= 0.25 become 1, etc. m <- c(0, 0.25, 1,  0.25, 0.5, 2,  0.5, 1, 3)

but then the reclassify function in the example doesn't use the include.lowest so it shouldn't be all values >= 0 but >0.

EDIT: I find the help page very confusing, and given the answer the example's explanation in the help page is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the way that `right` and `include.lowest` work are exactly the same as in R base function `cut`. For a simple illustration, I will use `cut` in below, with vector 1:10 and break points 1, 5, 10.

By default, `right = TRUE`, so all intervals will be left open and right closed, thus we have two intervals: `(1, 5]`, `(5, 10]`. Note these together give another left open right closed interval `(1, 10]`, where the lowest `1` is not included. `include.lowest = TRUE` will consider `[1, 10]` and do `[1,5]`, `(5,10]`. Compare

```
cut(1:10, right = TRUE, breaks = c(1, 5, 10))
# [1] <NA>   (1,5]  (1,5]  (1,5]  (1,5]  (5,10] (5,10] (5,10] (5,10] (5,10]
#Levels: (1,5] (5,10]

cut(1:10, right = TRUE, breaks = c(1, 5, 10), include.lowest = TRUE)
# [1] [1,5]  [1,5]  [1,5]  [1,5]  [1,5]  (5,10] (5,10] (5,10] (5,10] (5,10]
#Levels: [1,5] (5,10]
```

Now, if we set `right = FALSE`, all intervals will be left closed and right open: `[1, 5)`, `[5, 10)`. In this case, the `include.lowest = TURE` essentially includes the highest value. Compare

```
cut(1:10, right = FALSE, breaks = c(1, 5, 10))
# [1] [1,5)  [1,5)  [1,5)  [1,5)  [5,10) [5,10) [5,10) [5,10) [5,10) <NA>  
#Levels: [1,5) [5,10)

cut(1:10, right = FALSE, breaks = c(1, 5, 10), include.lowest = TRUE)
# [1] [1,5)  [1,5)  [1,5)  [1,5)  [5,10] [5,10] [5,10] [5,10] [5,10] [5,10]
#Levels: [1,5) [5,10]
```

---

Back to `raster::reclassify`.

> I find it confusing because the example given on the reclassify help file says that
>
> all values >= 0 and <= 0.25 become 1, etc. `m <- c(0, 0.25, 1,  0.25, 0.5, 2,  0.5, 1, 3)`

Why? With above `m`, you have `rcl` matrix:

```
matrix(m, ncol = 3L, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to", value)))
#     from   to value
#[1,] 0.00 0.25     1
#[2,] 0.25 0.50     2
#[3,] 0.50 1.00     3
```

With `right = TRUE` and `include.lowest = FALSE` (default behaviour), you have

```
(0.00, 0,25]   --->   1
(0.25, 0.50]   --->   2
(0.50, 1.00]   --->   3
```

with `right = TRUE` and `include.lowest = TRUE`, you have

```
[0.00, 0,25]   --->   1
(0.25, 0.50]   --->   2
(0.50, 1.00]   --->   3
```

Comment: with right set by default to true the 0 should not be included. "all values >=0"

Comment: you have to change your answer because it does not address the inconsistency with the reclassify help page.