# How to fit a survival model for each quartile of a variable?

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis, quantile

I tried to fit a survival model for each quartile of one variable in a dataset. Taking the data set of lunge cancer available in `survival` package as example

```
library(survival)
datalung <- lung
attach(datalung)
fit<- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ quantile(age)[2:5],type = "kaplan-meier")
```

But I get a error about length of the variables are different. I want to fit four models, one for each quartile.

*Less than or equal to 25%*

*Greater than 25 and less equal to 50%*

*Greater than 50% and less equal to 75%*

*Greater than 75%*

How I can do it?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I tried using quantile(age)[2:5] but doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `quantile` returns 5 values, at `prob = seq(0, 1, 0.25)`. I think you want to use `cut` to get a factor variable:

```
library(survival)
datalung <- lung
datalung$fage <- with(datalung, cut(age, quantile(age), include = TRUE))

## don't use `attach()`; use the `data` argument of model fitting routine
fit <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ fage, data = datalung, type="kaplan-meier")

#Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ fage, data = datalung, 
#    type = "kaplan-meier")
#
#              n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
#fage=[39,56] 58     39    337     239     457
#fage=(56,63] 59     41    348     245     574
#fage=(63,69] 55     39    329     285     477
#fage=(69,82] 56     46    283     222     361
```

---

**Follow-up**

@42- has also used `quantile`, by what he obtained is the "left closed and right open" intervals.

Your question reads:

- Less than or equal to 25%
- Greater than 25 and less equal to 50%
- Greater than 50% and less equal to 75%
- Greater than 75%

so clearly you want "left open and right closed" intervals. Therefore, my code is exactly what you want.

[What is the meaning of include.lowest in reclassify raster package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976217/what-is-the-meaning-of-include-lowest-in-reclassify-raster-package-r/38977067#38977067) explained `include.lowest` and `right` arguments inside `cut` and `raster::reclassify` in great details. Now let's compare:

```
## my factor
table(with(datalung, cut(age, quantile(age), include.lowest = TRUE)))
#[39,56] (56,63] (63,69] (69,82] 
#     58      59      55      56 

## 42-'s factor
table(with(datalung, cut(age, quantile(age), include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)))
#[39,56) [56,63) [63,69) [69,82] 
#     49      57      55      67
```

Comment: What the include=TRUE inside the cut function do?

Comment: There is a strange thing that happens when I use the autoplot() function of the ggplot2 package. The quantiles are not ordered like in fit.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using my preferred method of creating quartile indicators:

```
library(survival)
datalung <- lung
detach(datalung)  # Agree with Zheyuan Li that attach()-ing is dangerous practice.
fit3<- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ findInterval(age, quantile(age)[-5]), 
                     data=datalung, type = "kaplan-meier")
```

Needed to drop the fifth item in the vector is splitting values because findInterval has splits that are closed on the left and would have gotten a fifth groups that only had the max of age. Notice that our quartile count results are different. His method lost cases and not just at the minimum or maximun groups. Where they went, ...  I'm not sure yet:

```
> fit3
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ findInterval(age, quantile(age)[-5]), 
    data = datalung, type = "kaplan-meier")

                                        n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
findInterval(age, quantile(age)[-5])=1 49     32    320     226     533
findInterval(age, quantile(age)[-5])=2 57     41    340     245     433
findInterval(age, quantile(age)[-5])=3 55     39    310     267     524
findInterval(age, quantile(age)[-5])=4 67     53    285     229     363
```

Your question to Zheyuan Li about the ordering of the levels in ggplot exposes another pitfall of using cut, at least if one does not supply names with a "label"-argument. Levels are ordered lexically, and "[" is `>` than "(":

```
> levels(datalung$fage)
[1] "[39,56]" "(56,63]" "(63,69]" "(69,82]"
> "[" < "("
[1] FALSE
```

To address the issue about my use of quantile versus @ZheyuanLi use and his incorrect characterization of my method, one only needs to examine:

```
> quantile(datalung$age)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
  39   56   63   69   82 

> with( datalung, table( findInterval(age, quantile(datalung$age)[-5] )))

 1  2  3  4 
49 57 55 67
```

So most of the difference is how the age of 56 was handled:

```
>  sum(lung$age==56)
[1] 9
```

Was attempting to address the labeling when using `cut()` (which wasn't really my responsibility anyway, was it?):

```
> library(ggplot2)  # checked to make sure I have the most recent version per CRAN
> autoplot(fit2)
Error: Objects of type survfit not supported by autoplot.
```

Comment: I don't think that explains the difference. We both used `quantile`. Saying I cut the range into equal parts  incorrectly describes my method.

Comment: You would probably want to create the numeric vector outside of `ggplot` and `factor()` it with labels like : `labels=paste0("Q", 1:4)`. This actually worked fairly well with `cut` once I figured out that `autoplot.survfit` was in the `survMisc` package rather than in ggplot2.

Comment: @42- Actually I'm using ggfortify package, and autoplot() function, but I will try it this numeric vector.

Comment: Another idea: `factor( findInterval(age,  quantile(datalung$age)[2:4]+.0001 ), labels=paste0("Q", 1:4) )`   ... done outside of the survfit call..  this adds a "fuzz factor that moves the cutpoints for the quartiles just a little bit above the integer values. There may also be a `type` for `quantile` that would be more appropriate for an integer set that you want to have "right" boundaries. You should edit your question to make clear what non-base packages you are using.